# How can I tell DBD::CSV to use a comma as the decimal seperator?

Tags: perl, csv, dbi

I'm trying to use a German-style CSV file with DBI and [DBD::CSV](https://metacpan.org/module/DBD%3a%3aCSV). This, in turn, uses [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV) to parse the file. I want to query the data in that file using SQL.

Let's look at the file first. It is separated by semicolons (`;`), and the numbers in it look like this: `5,23`, which is equivalent to the English `5.23`.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use DBI;

# create the database handle
my $dbh = DBI->connect(
  'dbi:CSV:',
  undef, undef,
  {
    f_dir => '.',
    f_schema => undef,
    f_ext => '.csv',
    f_encoding => 'latin-1',
    csv_eol => "\n",
    csv_sep_char => ';',
    csv_tables => {
      foo => {
        file => 'foo.csv',
        #skip_first_row => 0,
        col_names => [ map { "col$_" } (1..3)  ], # see annotation below
      },
    },
  },
) or croak $DBI::errstr;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(
  'SELECT col3 FROM foo WHERE col3 > 80.50 ORDER BY col3 ASC'
);
$sth->execute;

while (my $res = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
  say $res->{col3};
}
```

Now, this looks quite nice. The problem is that the SQL (meaning SQL::Statement, which is somewhere down the line from DBI and DBD::CSV) does not regard the data in `col3`, which is a floating-point value with a comma in the middle, as a float. Instead, it treats the column as an integer, because it doesn't understand the comma.

Here's some example data:

```
foo;foo;81,90
bar;bar;80,50
baz;baz;80,70
```

So the above code with this data will result in one line of output: `81,90`. Of course, that is wrong. It used the `int()` part of `col3` with the comparison, which is right, but not what I want.

Question: **How can I tell it to treat the numbers with the comma as float?**

Things I've thought about:

- I've not found any built-in way in Text::CSV to do this. I'm not sure where in Text::CSV I could hook this in, or if there is a mechanism in Text::CSV to put such things in at all.
- I don't know if it poses a problem that DBD::CSV wants to use Text::CSV_XS if possible.
- Maybe I can do it later, after the data has been read and is already stored away somewhere, but I'm not yet sure where the right access point is.
- I understand that the stuff is stored in SQL::Statement. I don't yet know where. This could be handy somehow.

Changing the source CSV file to have dots instead of commas is **not** an option.

I'm open for all kinds of suggestions. Other approaches to the whole CSV via SQL thing are welcome, too. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to access this data through SQL?

Comment: Who is this "it" that you speak of? "It doesn't understand the comma", "It used the int() part of col3"... Perl? A module? The database?

Comment: @Borodin the general idea is to have multiple data sources. We are trying to upgrade from `open`ing and `<>`ing the CSV file to a DB-based approach, where the DB will be mysql or sqlite. The first step is supposed to be building SQL, but using the CSV file. There are other processes involved with the CSV file that we do not want to break. So, yes, I'd like to do it with SQL.

Comment: @TLP that would be some module involved with executing the query. Probably something within the DBI. The goal is to get that query to work.

Comment: @simbabque If you don't know what "it" is, then how are we to possibly understand your question: "How can I tell **it** to treat the numbers with the comma as float?"

Comment: @simbabque Why not make a case for storing numbers with `.` as decimal seperator in the backend? Using a `,` instead is a *user interface* decision and therefore should only affect in- and output operations, but not the internals. Converting the seperators *is* an option, even if only in a tempfile. `tr/,././` should do it.

Comment: @amon the tempfile might be a good idea. I think I might do that if all else fails. Thanks for that. Right now, I'd like to understand this baby a bit better.

Comment: Note that as far as `Text::CSV` is concerned *everything* is a text field. It is only SQL that differentiates between text and numeric data so as to determine how its operators and functions behave.

Comment: @Borodin I'm aware of that. My though was that the easiest way to get rid of the commas would be to grab them while they are first imported by Text::CSV.

Comment: @TLP I edited the question to make the 'it' a little more clear.

Comment: @simbabque Perhaps it could be done somehow by using the german locale settings for decimal point numbers? POSIX module?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to write a user-defined function using [`SQL::Statement::Functions`](https://metacpan.org/module/SQL%3a%3aStatement%3a%3aFunctions) (already loaded as part of [`DBD::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBD%3a%3aCSV)).

This program does what you want. Adding `0.0` to the transformed string is strictly unnecessary, but it makes the point about the purpose of the subroutine. (Note also your typo in the `f_encoding` parameter to the `connect` call.)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
  'dbi:CSV:',
  undef, undef,
  {
    f_dir => '.',
    f_schema => undef,
    f_ext => '.csv',
    f_encoding => 'latin-1',
    csv_eol => "\n",
    csv_sep_char => ';',
    csv_tables => {
      foo => {
        file => 'test.csv',
        #skip_first_row => 0,
        col_names => [ map { "col$_" } (1..3)  ], # see annotation below
      },
    },
  },
) or croak $DBI::errstr;

$dbh->do('CREATE FUNCTION comma_float EXTERNAL');

sub comma_float {
  my ($self, $sth, $n) = @_;
  $n =~ tr/,/./;
  return $n + 0.0;
}

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(
  'SELECT col3 FROM foo WHERE comma_float(col3) > 80.50 ORDER BY col3 ASC'
);
$sth->execute;

while (my $res = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
  say $res->{col3};
}
```

**output**

```
80,70
81,90
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is great, I wasn't aware this was possible. Still, this means the function gets called for each row, in each query? I did a quick benchmark, and it increased the duration of `prepare` and `execute` from 1.1s to 1.6s. I believe that it would in the long run be faster to change the underlying SQL::Statement::RAM::Table. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't believe the `prepare` takes 1.6 *seconds*? Are you timing multiple executions? The golden rule of optimisation is not to do it until you find you need to. Anyway a 45% increase in delay isn't that great: waiting fifteen minutes instead of ten is no big deal. It looks like `SQL::Statement::RAM` is meant for use internally, and I doubt if there's anything you could do that way that is different from `CREATE TEMP TABLE footemp AS SELECT col1, col2, comma_float(col3)`.

Comment: I'm not timing multiple executions. `my $t0 = Benchmark->new;
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( 'SELECT col2, col3 FROM artikel WHERE comma_float(col3) > 90.50 ORDER BY col3 ASC' );
$sth->execute;
my $t1 = Benchmark->new;
my $sth2 = $dbh->prepare( 'SELECT col2, col3 FROM artikel WHERE col3 > 90.50 ORDER BY col3 ASC' );
$sth2->execute;
my $t2 = Benchmark->new;
say timestr(timediff($t1, $t0));
say timestr(timediff($t2, $t1));` Ugly, I know. It says: `1.6931 wallclock secs ( 1.12 usr +  0.06 sys =  1.19 CPU)
1.16507 wallclock secs ( 0.69 usr +  0.05 sys =  0.73 CPU)` My file has about 20k rows.

Comment: @simbabque: Ah well I assumed you were using the code and data in your question :) I'm getting 1.6s and 1.8s for a 30,000-record file. What is the size of your expected data? I would have thought under two seconds was fine. The problem seems to be more to do with `DBD::CSV` than the user-defined function - you can't expect to get high speed from a CSV file! If this is a game-breaker you should just read the CSV files into SQLite tables and work from there.

Comment: @simbabque: You should set up a `timethese` to compare the speeds properly.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear on the size. 20k is a real-life file. All this stuff is in an e-commerce CGI application. We were thinking about SQlite as the second step. The fun part is that just reading the file (sometimes multiple times per invocation) without a CSV module is really fast. It's just ugly and not very practical. We're working on the SQlite now.

Comment: Running each for 20 CPU seconds (`-20`) revealed 1.11s/iter vs 0.864s/iter. That's +28% and -22%.

Comment: @simbabque: Well that's half of the 45% you had before, but still rather more than the 12% I'm getting. I still think that you should be fine with 1.11s if 0.86s is acceptable. At least your problem isn't with the user-defined function, but rather that `DBD::CSV` is slower than you would like.

Comment: I agree with the later part. I never said I was ok with the 0.86s, though. Maybe this whole approach isn't what I'm looking for after all. Still, thank you very much for your help, it is quite appreciated! =)